# How do you use an array / object in the layout draw function?

Tags: python

I have multiple rows which all share the same properties. I would like to put all the rows into an array, and then modify the properties per item in the layout. How is this possible?

```
row1Angle = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
    name = "Angle",
    min = 0,
    max=pi/2,
    subtype="ANGLE"
)

row2Angle = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
    name = "Angle",
    min = 0,
    max=pi/2,
    subtype="ANGLE"
)

def draw(self, context):
    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text="Row 1")
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(self, "row1Angle")


    row = layout.row()
    row.label(text="Row 2")
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(self, "row2Angle")
```

The above works, but is not really scaleable/maintainable and adds complications when actually processing these values. Desired behaviour would be something like this:

```
## Desired behaviour ########

def class Row():
    angle = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name = "Angle",
        min = 0,
        max=pi/2,
        subtype="ANGLE"
    )

rows = []

for i in range(0, 1):
    rows.append(Row())


def draw(self, context):

    for i in range(0, 1):
         row = layout.row()
         row.label(text=plot.savefig(f'Row {i}'))
         row = layout.row()
         row.prop(self.rows[i], "angle")
```

Unfortunately, this does not work cause of the following error "Function.data expected a AnyType type". Which is caused by using `self.rows[i]`, instead of `self`.